# Django Rest Framework - define API from an existing view

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm writing my django app, and i have a lot of views that already returns a JSONResponse object, for example:

```
def power_on_relay(request):
'''View that Power on one of the available relays'''
try:
    relay_id = get_or_raise(request, 'relay_id')


    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(relay_id, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(relay_id, True)
    pin_status = GPIO.input(relay_id)


    return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'message': 'Relay {0} was powered on'.format(relay_id), 'data': None})
except Exception as ex:
    return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': str(ex), 'data': ''})
```

Now, i need to expose some of these views as "API" and i need to manage the authentication, throttling, etc... 
So, i was wondering if it's possible using DRF and without writing tons of redundant code.

I mean, there is a short way to do that? something like a decorator that doesn't change my web application behaivor?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [`api_view`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) decorator

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def power_on_relay(request):
    '''View that Power on one of the available relays'''
    try:
        relay_id = get_or_raise(request, 'relay_id')


        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(relay_id, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(relay_id, True)
        pin_status = GPIO.input(relay_id)

        return Response({'success': True, 'message': 'Relay {0} was powered on'.format(relay_id), 'data': None})
    except Exception as ex:
        return Response({'success': False, 'message': str(ex), 'data': ''})
```

Comment: Thanks, and how i can implement the documentation of these api? i mean, there is some CLEAN way to document the parameter that i need to give to the endpoint api?

Comment: @VirtApp I think that in your situation you should use explicit schema definition https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#explicit-schema-definition But over time it could become hard to maintain. I would adivise that you start refactoring your views into class based ones. This will reduce boilerplate and will give you auto generated API documentation